# Can I use acts_as_tenant in the devise user model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, multi-tenant

My devise MODEL name is User. When I use it in combination with acts_as_tenant,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   acts_as_tenant(:tenant)
```

I get some weird behaviour: When users log into one tenant, everything is fine. As soon somebody signs into another tenant, the users of the first tenant are kicked out.

I would like to set the User model to acts_as_tenant, as the users should be administered within each tenant.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed:
https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant/issues/20

This appeared to be an issue with thread safety.